# Sort files by name and number

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file

I am trying to sort the following list of files

```
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00010-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00011-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00012-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00013-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00014-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00015-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00016-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0001-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0002-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0003-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0004-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0005-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0006-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0007-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0008-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0009-R.xml
```

As you can see it starting with 10, 11, 12 ..... then back to 1.

How can i sort them in this correct order?

```
  C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0001-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0002-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0003-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0004-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0005-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0006-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0007-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0008-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0009-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00010-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00011-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00012-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00013-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00014-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00015-R.xml
    C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00016-R.xml
```

I can use a batch file or even a simple code.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I USED THE FOLLOWING COMMAND TO READ THE FILES

```
echo off
for /r %%a in (*.xml) do echo %%a >> get_files.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! (Only for Linux)

```
sort -t $'-' -k3 -n file.txt
```

Output:

```
# sort -t $'-' -k3 -n file.txt
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0001-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0002-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0003-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0004-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0005-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0006-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0007-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0008-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-0009-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00010-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00011-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00012-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00013-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00014-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00015-R.xml
C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\ACC-BANQUE_76401-00016-R.xml
```

Save file (redirect output using `>` )

```
sort -t $'-' -k3 -n file.txt > new_formated_file
```

Comment: Ummm that's unix stupid me. lololol I gave me an error in Dos. Well i'll jump to unix then. I'll do it right away just a couple of minutes

Comment: is this a directories listing or just and single file contain all data.

Comment: In the directory they are sorted correctly. But once I use a batch file to copy every path, i get the above listing.

Used batch file : 
echo off
for /r %%a in (*.xml) do echo %%a >> get_files.txt

Comment: I would say copy file over `Unix/Linux` and sort it :)

Comment: That's what i was going to do BRB

Comment: Ok ok almost got it Just one correction I think that it should be 
# sort -t $'-' -k2 -n file.txt (K2 instead of K3) and how can I save the sorted file? 

So  let me see if I got it right: You tokenized the file and used the 3rd part which are the numbers. sheesh this is really clever

Comment: I have edited my answer, how to save new file. use `>` redirect and send output to new file.

Answer (score 2):

just use a batch oneliner on the `cmd` prompt:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %x in ('(for %a in ("C:\DOCUMENTS\FLUX Melange\MultiXml\*.xml"^) do @for /f "tokens=3 delims=-" %b in ("%~na"^) do @for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %c in ("%~b"^) do @set "sorty=000%c"^&call set "sorty=%sorty:~-4%"^&call echo %sorty% %a^)^|sort') do @echo %y
```

Note: this might not work with XP, still not tested.

Answer (score 1):

The first list is sorted in lexicographical order.

Can you add one more zero to the files `[1..9]` ?

Using `cmd`, `dir /O` will sort the files in lexicographical order.

Comment: hi Ayoubi, Adding a zero like 0001 -> 00001

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This batch will create a `files.tx0` (with `##### filename`), then `files.tx1` (ordered `files.tx0`) and then read files part from `files.tx1` to `files.txt`:

```
DEL files.tx0
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R %%a IN (*.xml) DO FOR /F "DELIMS=- TOKENS=3" %%b IN ("%%~na") DO (
    SET N=0%%b
    ECHO !N:~-5! %%a>>files.tx0
)
SORT files.tx0 >files.tx1
DEL files.txt
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,*" %%i IN (files.tx1) DO >>files.txt ECHO %%j
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers sort *the list of names*; this mean that you must run the program every time you want the files sorted in order. The Batch program below *renames the files*, so you must run it just one time and then the files will appear sorted no matter how you access they.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A-D *.xml') do (
   set number=%%c
   if "!number:~4!" equ "" (
      set pth=%%a
      ren "%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d" "!pth:~-3!-%%b-0%%c-%%d"
   )
)
```